# FBSDKMessageDialog does not send video in message in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, video, fbsdk

I am using the following code to share a video on Facebook:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.myApp getVideoAssetURL]];
    // it returns AssetURL of video
FBSDKShareVideo *video = [[FBSDKShareVideo alloc] init];
video.videoURL = videoURL;

FBSDKShareVideoContent *content = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
content.video = video;

[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
```

this code is working but when I replace the following line of code

```
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
```

with

```
[FBSDKMessageDialog showWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

to send the video in private message on Facebook. The messenger shows friends list but does not show the video and keeps "Send" button disable after selecting friends.

Is there any other way to do this or it can be done by using FBSDKShareDialog?

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using and how big is the video you are trying to share? There is a file size limit of 12MB max, maybe this is what you're running into. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#videos

Comment: we are sure, size is less then 12mb , but still no success